# How can one do start - pause - continue - pause - continue - pause with the threading.timer?

Tags: python

How can one do start - pause - continue - pause - continue - pause with the threading.timer ?

What I have do so far :=

```
class Scheduling(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
            self.schedule = None
            threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):                                
            self.schedule = threading.Timer(2, self.run).start()
```

in main, I have call like :

```
sched = Scheduling()
sched.start()
```

Comment: What is being started and paused? The main thread? A different thread? Something else? How should it be continued?

Comment: @HenryGomersall threading.Timer

Comment: You want to pause the timer? Not easily afaict. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: @HenryGomersall If it is tricky, how can I kill, or cancel, whatever, the timer ?

Comment: the timer is stoppable with '.cancel()'. T

Comment: @mkind I have wrote `def fin(self): self.schedule.cancel()` but it is not stopped Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have wrote def fin(self): self.schedule.cancel() but it is not stopped Why?

Your self.schedule object is no threading.Timer object. The start() method [does not return any timer objects actually](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.start). You need to create the timer explicitly.

```
class Scheduling(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
            self.schedule = None
            threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):                                
            self.schedule = threading.Timer(2, self.run)
            self.schedule.start()

    def cancel(self):
            self.schedule.cancel()
```

I did not tested it. However, I am not sure, what you want the Timer to do. After two seconds it will call run to restart a new timer?